# ESRI World Light Gray Basemap - without labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am using the "World Light Gray Base" as my basemap in ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop. Is there any way I could turn off the street labels (they show up on ex. scale 1:12000)? I unchecked the "Reference" layer and it got rid of cities' labels, but not street names. Maybe any way around?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. The labels are a part of the tiles.